# Haskell Aeson how to decode / parse based on `Value` type rather than `ByteString`?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have the following function:

```
parseUserBasic :: ByteString -> Either String [Either String UserBasic]
parseUserBasic x = do 
  xx <- parseItems x
  pure $ fmap (eitherDecode . encode) (items xx)
```

However it's not very efficient because of `pure $ fmap (eitherDecode . encode) (items xx)` - we are JSON encoding a `Object` into a `ByteString`, which we then decode into a `UserBasic`. Is there a way to do this directly? I assume this function would have the type `FromJSON a => Value -> Maybe a`.

The complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module UserBasic where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.String.Conversions
import Data.ByteString.Lazy

data UserBasic = UserBasic
  { email :: String
  , name :: String
  , address_1 :: Maybe String
  , address_2 :: Maybe String
  , address_3 :: Maybe String
  , address_4 :: Maybe String
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Items = Items
  { items :: [Object]
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Items where
instance ToJSON Items where
  toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions

instance FromJSON UserBasic where
     parseJSON = withObject "Person" $ \v -> UserBasic
         <$> v .: "email"
         <*> ((++) . (++ " ") <$> v .: "first_name" <*> v .: "last_name")
         <*> v .: "first_name"
         <*> v .: "first_name"
         <*> v .: "first_name"
         <*> v .: "first_name"

parseItems :: ByteString -> Either String Items
parseItems = eitherDecode

parseUserBasic :: ByteString -> Either String [Either String UserBasic]
parseUserBasic x = do 
  xx <- parseItems x
  pure $ fmap (eitherDecode . encode) (items xx)
```

Comment: Would it be [fromJSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:fromJSON)? But I guess it's simpler to define a list of `UserBasic` and decode the JSON directly into it.

Comment: Just to double-check: the idiomatic thing is to just use `eitherDecode :: ByteString -> Either String [UserBasic]` (or a minor variant if the existence of the top-level "items" key is a requirement handed down from heaven). Are you sure you don't want that?

Comment: To be clear: when I said "just use", I meant "just use `eitherDecode` instead of `parseUserBasic`".

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. But the JSON value I get (from an API) indeed has the users under the `items` key. So I don't see how just using `eitherDecode :: ByteString -> Either String [UserBasic]` would work. In terms of the 'variant' -  I assume that would what `parseUserBasic` is - unless there is another alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @snak pointing out `fromJSON` which is defined as:

```
-- | Convert a value from JSON, failing if the types do not match.
fromJSON :: (FromJSON a) => Value -> Result a
fromJSON = parse parseJSON
```

Which lead me to the solution:

```
fff :: Value -> Either String UserBasic
fff x = parseEither parseJSON $ x

parseUserBasic :: ByteString -> Either String [Either String UserBasic]
parseUserBasic x = do 
  xx <- parseItems x
  pure $ fmap (fff) (fmap Object $ items xx)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following abbreviated code:

```
newtype Items = Items
  { items :: [UserBasic]
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Items
instance ToJSON Items where
  toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions

parseUserBasic :: ByteString -> Either String [UserBasic]
parseUserBasic bs = items <$> eitherDecode bs

-- OR, even better in many cases, don't bother unwrapping Items:

parseItems :: ByteString -> Either String Items
parseItems = eitherDecode -- why even bother naming parseItems lmao
```

Don't first decode to `Object`, then do further decoding; just decode directly to the type you care about.